# How to call Paths.get with a List of String

Tags: scala, overloading, variadic-functions

I have an error with the following code and I don't understand why the compiler doesn't find the good method between both alternatives :

```
scala> import java.nio.file.Paths
scala> val paths = List("a","b","c")
scala> Paths.get(paths:_*)

<console>:33: error: overloaded method value get with alternatives:
  (x$1: java.net.URI)java.nio.file.Path <and>
  (x$1: String,x$2: <repeated...>[String])java.nio.file.Path
 cannot be applied to (String)
              Paths.get(paths:_*)
                ^
```

I've found the following workaround, but is there a cleaner way ?

```
scala> Paths.get("", paths:_*)
res5: java.nio.file.Path = a/b/c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Paths.get(paths.head,paths.tail:_*)
```

Comment: my bad, I was thinking the signature was `get(String... path)` but it is `get(String first, String... more)`